# Super()__init__ on multiple parent classes for Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
class Base1:
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        print("Base1 __init__")

class Base2:
    def __init__(self):
        print("Base2 __init__")

class Derived(Base1, Base2):
     pass

# Create an instance of the Derived class
d = Derived()
```

This outputs:

```
   
Base2 __init__
Base1 __init__
```

What principle or mechanism makes it print `Base2 __init__` ?

Isn't MRO on Derived supposed to be Base1->Base2, and thus only Base1's **init** should be run?

Comment: So on a quick test, I found that `Base2 __init__` was coming from `super().__init__()`. However, `print(super())` gives `<super: <class 'Base1'>, <Derived object>>`.

Answer (score 4):

It's the same principle as always, `super` gets *the next method in the method resolution order*.

Now, here is the mro of `Derived`:

```
>>> Derived.mro()
[<class '__main__.Derived'>, <class '__main__.Base1'>, <class '__main__.Base2'>, <class 'object'>]
```

So when `__init__` is resolved on `Derived`, it first checks if `Derived.__init__` exists. It doesn't, so then it checks `Base1.__init__`, and finds it, and it is called.

Inside `Base1.__init__`, you call `super().__init__()`. Now this is crucial to understand, the implicit arguments are `super(Base1, self)`. So, since `self` here is an instance of `Derived`, the mro of `Derived` is consulted. And then super decides to take **the next class in the MRO** after the class that was passed to super. So:

```
[<class '__main__.Derived'>, <class '__main__.Base1'>, <class '__main__.Base2'>, <class 'object'>]
                              ^^^                      ^^^
                              we are here              so we pick this one
```

And the next class in the MRO after `Base1` is `Base2`, so it calls `Base2.__init__`

This is all how it's supposed to work. This is the beauty behind super!